# Display result in horizontally using list style

Tags: php, html

I tried to make it display all result horizontally using float:LEFT in LI tag.
But it show each row only display two result.

Here my code:

```
<div id="product_inner_content">
<?php
require('database_connection.php');
if (@mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$latest_tyres = "SELECT * FROM tblInventory WHERE LATEST='L'";
$result = mysqli_query ($mydatabase, $latest_tyres);

//ccreating a list style                            
echo "<ul style='list-style-type:none;display:inline;padding:0;'>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{
   //display result in <li>
   echo "<li id=='Number_".$row['IMLITM']."' style='width:230px;height:320px;background-color:green;display:inline;float:left'>";
   echo "<div style='width:220px;height:320px;background-color:black;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto'>";
   echo "</div>";
   echo "</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";

mysqli_close($mydatabase);
?>
</div>
```

I had set my product_inner_content div to become overflow-y:auto;

The result of this code is like this :

```
Item 1       Item 2

Item 3

Item 4
```

But I want this:

```
Item 1     Item 2   Item 3   Item 4
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it is a best practice to make an external css than inline styles. Maybe you can add id(#) to that ul element

**HTML**

```
 echo "<ul id = 'mylist'>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
       //display result in <li>
       echo "<li id=='Number_".$row['IMLITM']."'>";
       echo "<div>";
       echo "</div>";
       echo "</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
```

**CSS**

```
ul#mylist li{
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background-color:green;
    float: left;
}

ul#mylist li div{
    background-color:black;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto
}
```

Comment: It still the result out where the Item 3 and Item 4 still on below.

Comment: That is because you've added width and height in each li element, you should use padding for the spacing instead of adding height and width. 
I've already updated the code above.

I don't know what is the use of that div element inside li though.

Comment: Yes..I had tried your code, but the result in my site is vertically. Black DIV is display vertically in a straight line

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with your markup, can you provide the external css code as well?

I already created a fiddle on this see: http://jsfiddle.net/henf7/
and it seems to look good though.

Answer (score 0):

set the width for this div `<div id="product_inner_content">`

```
#product_inner_content{ width:500px}
```

Comment: It should not related to the DIV width.But I set the width to 700px and overflow-x:auto